How accurate is this song translation Malum Malum (Bad Apple)?
I saw this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgF96RRcrP4 of a Latin cover of "Bad Apple!!" (original lyrics in Japanese but has been translated into many languages) and like the song very much. I think it would be cool to learn the Latin version, but I don't know enough Latin to tell if it's accurate or if it's authentic Latin. How accurate is the translation? And how well would it convey the meaning and style of the original song to a native speaker?
Note: I'm not entirely sure which version this Latin translation is based upon, I think it's the Japanese lyrics, and the original Japanese lyrics contained many cultural references not obvious in existing English versions (see https://www.reddit.com/r/touhou/comments/p1gmc5/comment/jtfgr9m ).
Below are the Latin lyrics in question and the English translation of it provided by the author:
Etiam medio in tempore fluente
Sic apathia saltat turbinea, turbinea
Non video cor meum, est discedens a me
Et etiam nunc non sum motata

Sed etiamsi non procedo nec moveo
Tamen deripior per temporis fissuras porro
Non curo, non posco aliquem ubiquomque
Quia ego sum ego solummodo

Somnium estne? Nihil percipione?
Verba sunt inania etiamsi vocata
Tristimoniae causa tota sum fatigata
Atque malo vivere sine emotione

Loquaris etiamsi cum verbo mirabili
Semper cor meum absit, numquam quoniam audit
Si mutare audeo omnia pro alio
Tamen nunc omne verto, pro atro id mutabo

Estne ei hominum futura, relicuuum?
Et hic orbis terrarum, estne hic meum fatum?
Anima nunc doletne? Maesta nunc sentione?
Nulla res de me ipsa, nulla mihi cognita

Modo cedendi causa tota sum fatigata
Sic quomodo aliquem, quare homines curem?
Et si etiam ego procedo atque muto
A, si vere procedo sic in albam me verto

Etiam medio in tempore fluente
Sic apathia saltat turbinea, turbinea
Non video cor meum, est discedens a me
Et etiam nunc non sum motata

Sed etiamsi non procedo nec moveo
Tamen deripior per temporis fissuras porro
Non curo, non posco aliquem ubiquomque
Quia ego sum ego solummodo

Somnium estne? Nihil percipione?
Verba sunt inania etiamsi vocata
Tristimoniae causa tota sum fatigata
Atque malo vivere sine emotione

Loquaris etiamsi cum verbo mirabili
Semper cor meum absit, numquam quoniam audit
Si mutare audeo omnia pro alio
Tamen nunc omne verto, pro atro id mutabo

Eruntne res futurae postquam horae perditae? 
Et sumne ego ipsa hic in regione ea?
Et si de me loqueris, uno verbo uteris
Notatio prorsissima, presse: "supervacua"

Et sumne ego ipsa hic in regione ea?
Ac sumne ego ipsa vere in tali hora?
Si mutare valebo me ipsam pro alio
A, si vere procedam, num in albam me vertam?

Eho, somnium estne? Nihil percipione?
Verba sunt inania etiamsi vocata
Tristimoniae causa tota sum fatigata
Atque malo vivere sine emotione

Loquaris etiamsi cum verbo mirabili
Semper cor meum absit, numquam quoniam audit
Si mutare audeo omnia pro alio
Tamen nunc omne verto, pro atro id mutabo

Si movere incipio, si movere incipio
Tum omnes res deleo, tum omnes res deleo
Si maerere audeo, si maerere audeo
Nonne atrum cor meum totum fiet candidum

Cognovi nihil de te, cognovi nihil de me
Etiamnum nescio aliquam rem omnino
Et si omnia perdant cum meae genae hiscant
Ergo nunc omne verto, pro atro id mutabo

Even in the midst of flowing time
So dances apathy, swirling, swirling
I don't see my heart, it's moving away from me
And even now, I'm not moved
But even if I neither proceed nor move
I'm still being pulled further through the cracks of time
I don't care, I don't ask for anyone, anywhere
Because I am me, just that
Is it a dream? Am I not perceiving anything?
Words are empty, even if they are shouted
Because of the sadness, I am completely exhausted
And I would rather live without emotion
Even if you were to speak with astonishing word
My heart would always be absent, because it never listens
If I dare to change everything for something else
I still now turn everything, will exchange it for black
Is there a future, something left, for this one (out of all humans)?
And this world, is it my fate?
Does my soul hurt now? Do I, the sad one, feel now?
Nothing about myself, nothing is known to me
Just because of walking, I am completely exhausted
How should I care about anyone like that, why (care) about people?
And if even I proceed or change
Ah, if I really proceed, I will turn myself to white like this
Even in the midst of flowing time
Apathy dances like that, swirling, swirling
I don't see my heart, it is moving away from me
And even now, I'm not moved
But even if I neither proceed nor move
I'm still being pulled further through the cracks of time
I don't care, I don't ask for anyone, anywhere
Because I am me, just that
Is it a dream? Am I not perceiving anything?
Words are empty, even if they are shouted
Because of the sadness, I am completely exhausted
And I would rather live without emotion
Even if you were to speak with astonishing word
My heart would always be absent, because it never listens
If I dare to change everything for something else
I still now turn everything, will exchange it for black
Will there be a future after the wasted hours?
And do I myself exist here in this region?
And when you speak about me, you use one word
A very straightforward description, simply: "useless"
And do I myself exist here in this region?
And do I myself really exist in an hour like this?
If I'll be able to exchange myself for something else
Ah, if I actually were to proceed, would I turn myself to white?
Hey, is it a dream? Am I not perceiving anything?
Words are empty, even if they are shouted
Because of the sadness, I am completely exhausted
And I would rather live without emotion
Even if you were to speak with astonishing word
My heart would always be absent, because it never listens
If I dare to change everything for something else
I still now turn everything, will exchange it for black
If I start to move, if I start to move
Then I destroy everything, then I destroy everything
If I dare to mourn, if I dare to mourn
Won't my black heart fully become shiny white?
I have learned nothing about you, I have learned nothing about myself
Even now, I do not know anything at all
And if everything were to perish when my eyelids open
I therefore now turn everything, will exchange it for black

Here are the original Japanese lyrics, a more literal English translation and lyrics of a popular rhymed English version for reference:

流れてく　時の中ででも　気だるさが　ほらグルグル廻って
私から　離れる心も　見えないわ　そう知らない？
自分から　動くこともなく　時の隙間に　流され続けて
知らないわ　周りのことなど　私は私　それだけ
 
夢見てる？　なにも見てない？　語るも無駄な　自分の言葉？
悲しむなんて　疲れるだけよ　何も感じず　過ごせばいいの
戸惑う言葉　与えられても　自分の心　ただ上の空
もし私から　動くのならば　すべて変えるのなら　黒にする
 
こんな自分に　未来はあるの？　こんな世界に　私はいるの？
今切ないの？　今悲しいの？　自分の事も　わからないまま
歩むことさえ　疲れるだけよ　人のことなど　知りもしないわ
こんな私も　変われるのなら　もし変われるのなら　白になる？
 
流れてく　時の中ででも　気だるさがほら　グルグル廻って
私から　離れる心も　見えないわそう　知らない？
自分から　動くこともなく　時の隙間に　流され続けて
知らないわ　周りのことなど　私は私　それだけ？
 
夢見てる？　なにも見てない　語るも無駄な　自分の言葉？
悲しむなんて　疲れるだけよ　何も感じず　過ごせばいいの
戸惑う言葉　与えられても　自分の心　ただ上の空
もし私から　動くのならば　すべて変えるのなら　黒にする
 
無駄な時間に　未来はあるの？　こんな所に　私は居るの？
私のことを　言いたいならば　言葉にするのなら　「ろくでなし」
こんな所に　私はいるの？　こんな時間に　私はいるの？
こんな私も　変われるのなら　もし変われるのなら　白になる？
 
今夢見てる？　なにも見てない？　語るも無駄な　自分の言葉？
悲しむなんて　疲れるだけよ　何も感じず　過ごせばいいの
戸惑う言葉　与えられても　自分の心　ただ上の空
もし私から　動くのならば　すべて変えるのなら　黒にする
 
動くのならば　動くのならば　すべて壊すわ　すべて壊すわ
悲しむならば　悲しむならば　私の心　白く変われる？
 
貴方の事も　私のことも　全ての事も　まだ知らないの
重い目蓋を　開けたのならば　すべて壊すのなら　黒になれ!!!

Amid time flowing along, only languidness is circling on and on
I can’t see even my heart being pulled apart from me, don’t you ever know?
Without making a move, carried away in between the cracks of time
All the people around me I don’t know; this is who I am and that’s all
 
Am I dreaming? Do I see nothing? Is it just useless to speak my words?
I’ve gotten tired of being sad; all I want is to live feeling nothing at all
If I’m given bewildering remarks, my heart is like in the clouds up above
If I bring myself to make a move, if I change everything, I’ll paint it all black
 
Is there a future for me? Do I exist in a world like this?
Wondering if I’m painful or sad, I don’t know what’s all about me
I’ve gotten tired of walking anymore; I don’t care what people think about me
If I can ever change myself, will my heart be able to turn white?
 
Amid time flowing along, only languidness is circling on and on
I can’t see even my heart being pulled apart from me, don’t you ever know?
Without making a move, carried away in between the cracks of time
All the people around me I don’t know; this is who I am and that’s all
 
Am I dreaming? Do I see nothing? Is it just useless to speak my words?
I’ve gotten tired of being sad; all I want is to live feeling nothing at all
If I’m given hesitating words, my heart is like in the clouds up above
If I bring myself to make a move, if I change everything, I’ll paint it all black
 
Is there a future for wasteful time? Do I exist in a place like this?
If you want to tell about me, If there’s a word to describe me it’s like “good for nothing”
Do I exist in a place like this? Do I exist in time like this?
If I can ever change myself, will my heart be able to turn white?
 
Am I dreaming? Do I see nothing? Is it just useless to speak my words?
I’ve gotten tired of being sad; all I want is to live feeling nothing at all
If I’m given hesitating words, my heart is like in the clouds up above
If I bring myself to make a move, if I change everything, I’ll paint it all black
 
If I make a move, I’ll destroy everything for once and all
If I feel sad, will my heart be able to turn white?
 
I don’t know about you, me and everything around me
If I open up my heavy eyelids; if I were to destroy everything, let it all turn black

Ever on and on
I continue circling
With nothing but my hate
In a carousel of agony
'Til slowly I forget and my heart starts vanishing
And suddenly I see that I can't
Break free, I'm

Slipping through the cracks of a dark eternity
With nothing but my pain and a paralyzing agony
To tell me who I am! Who I was!
Uncertainty enveloping my mind
'Til I can't break free and

Maybe it's a dream, maybe nothing else is real
But it wouldn't mean a thing if I told you how I feel
So I'm tired of all the pain, all the misery inside
And I wish that I could live feeling nothing but the night

You could tell me what to say, you could tell me where to go
But I doubt that I would care and my heart would never know
If I make another move, there'll be no more turning back
Because everything would change and it all would fade to black

Will tomorrow ever come? Will I make it through the night?
Will there ever be a place for the broken in the light?
Am I hurting? Am I sad? Should I stay or should I go?
I've forgotten how to tell, did I ever even know?

Can I take another step? I've done everything I can
All the people that I see, they will never understand
If I find a way to change, if I step into the light
Then I'll never be the same and it all will fade to white

Ever on and on
I continue circling
With nothing but my hate
In a carousel of agony
'Til slowly I forget and my heart starts vanishing
And suddenly I see that I can't
Break free, I'm

Slipping through the cracks of a dark eternity
With nothing but my pain and a paralyzing agony
To tell me who I am! Who I was!
Uncertainty enveloping my mind
'Til I can't break free and

Maybe it's a dream, maybe nothing else is real
But it wouldn't mean a thing if I told you how I feel
So I'm tired of all the pain, all the misery inside
And I wish that I could live feeling nothing but the night

You could tell me what to say, you could tell me where to go
But I doubt that I would care and my heart would never know
If I make another move, there'll be no more turning back
Because everything would change and it all would fade to black

Will tomorrow ever come? Will I make it through the night?
Will there ever be a place for the broken in the light?
Am I hurting, am I sad? Should I stay or should I go?
I've forgotten how to tell, did I ever even know?

This time you're not hurting me! This time I will take a stand!
All the hatred in my eyes building up an evil plan
Standing lonely in the night, with the darkness by my side
Looking deep inside myself, and revealing only fright

If I make another move, if I take another step
Then it would all fall apart, there'd be nothing of me left
If I'm crying in the wind, if I'm crying in the night
Will there ever be a way? Will my heart return to white?

Can you tell me who you are? Can you tell me where I am?
I've forgotten how to see, I've forgotten if I can
If I open up my eyes, there'll be no more going back
'Cause I'll throw it all away and it all will fade to black

So I'm back here once again, so I'm back here once again
Can I ever make a change? Will my heart begin to mend?
Would you love me if I go? It feels like a heart attack
But still everything's the same and it all just fades to black


My initial impression is that it's a poor Latin translation from someone who is translating quite literally, with occasional grammatical mistakes. Some concrete things from the first few lines: (1) apathia, emotio, and tristimonia are strange word choices; (2) est discedens is possible but strained, (3) motata should be mota (or even better: moveor), (4) vocata is not the right word for shouted, (5) etc. etc.

@brianpck Thanks! I don't know any better. Is it possible that they are chosen to fit the correct number/type of syllables into a line? Because the song is fast and melodic and I think it wouldn't be easy to work with lyrics with a different number of syllables
